# Detect browser extensions using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

How i can detect browser(for example chrome) extension using JS or detect one particular extension, for example
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=ru

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if user has a third party Chrome extension installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39897925/check-if-user-has-a-third-party-chrome-extension-installed)

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to run code on a website to detect a browser extension, you can load chrome-extension://`extension_id`/manifest.json

http://blog.kotowicz.net/2012/02/intro-to-chrome-addons-hacking.html

Comment: im run var detect = function(base, if_installed, if_not_installed) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.onerror = if_not_installed;
    s.onload = if_installed;
    document.body.appendChild(s);
    s.src = base + '/manifest.json';
}
detect('chrome-extension://' + 'kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk', function() {alert('boom!');}); but its return error Denying load of chrome-extension://kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk/manifest.json. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

Comment: can yoy help me?im run but print error Denying load of chrome-extension://kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk/manifest.json